# Woocommerce custom state translation with wpml

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to translate woocommerce custom state
I found this code on woocommerce forum but it not translatable

```
/**
 * Add or modify States
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

  $states['XX'] = array(
    'XX1' => 'State 1', 
    'XX2' => 'State 2'
  );

  return $states;
}
```

I modified it like this, but im not sure that the code is correct

```
/**
 * Add or modify States
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

  $states['XX'] = array(
    'X'  => __( 'XX1', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'Y'  => __( 'YY2', 'woocommerce' ),
  );

  return $states;
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Yes that is correct, but you should replace 'woocommerce' by your theme domain… Then you will have to scan your theme for string translations, before to be able to translate them.

Comment: thank you very very much